# Convert Curve Animation into Keyframes from gltf Export

Tags: animation, keyframes, gltf

I've made a curve animation of a plant growing, and I need to bake everything into mesh keyframes to export a gltf model for a website I'm currently developing. The thing is that gltf doesn't export curves, so I've to convert everything into mesh, and when I do that everything is messed up. I've tried exporting it into alembic to get the mesh sequence cache and then exported it back into .mdd to get the sequence cache into keyframes and shape keys, but I can't get it to work.
Somebody please help me! Thanks
Some screenshot attached:

[image: final result]

[image: first keyframes]